# Resolving localhost in email template in WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

About reset password email template, in WSO2 IS, is there any params to render server IP?

For example, something like {first-name} tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, currently WSO2 IS doesn't support Server IP parameter in email templates.

If you are trying to generate recovery links with server IPs, I suggest it's better if you can use domain names.

Regards, 
Lasitha.